# Simple backup of folder on usb stick with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, backup

I'm a new user of AppleScript and I try to settle an script to backup a folder from my mac to a folder on a usb stick.

I started to create this script but it doesn't work.

```
tell application "Finder"

    duplicate folder "/Users/alex/Desktop/test/" to "/Volumes/myusb/test/" replacing yes

end tell
```

**Thanks for you help.**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
set SourceFolder to POSIX file "/Users/alex/Desktop/test/"
set TargetFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/myusb/"

tell application "Finder"

    if exists SourceFolder then

        try

            duplicate SourceFolder to TargetFolder replacing yes

        on error the error_message number the error_number
            display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end try

    end if


end tell
```

("POSIX file" is from the "StandardAdditions")